# flutter: child widget not rebuilt after parent rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart

**Version:**
Flutter-Version: 1.12.14 channel dev
Dart-Version: 2.7.0

**Question:**
  I wan write a Todo App. when i click floatbutton add a new Todo, but in some cases its not work well.

The problem in `Scaffold.body`, detials in code.

it work well when i use `TodoPage(todoList: _todoList)`.

`_pageList.elementAt(_activeIndex)` is not work when i submit textfield .

I found the `print('Build Home')`print after submit but `print('Build TodoPage')` not print.

why???

My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TodoList',
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}


class Home extends StatefulWidget{
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home>{
  List<String> _todoList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  TextEditingController _controller;
  List<Widget> _pageList;
  int _activeIndex;
  Widget _curPage;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _activeIndex = 0;
    _pageList = [TodoPage(todoList: _todoList,), OtherPage()];
    _curPage = _pageList[_activeIndex];
    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    print('build Home');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Todo'),),
      body: _pageList.elementAt(_activeIndex), // this is not work
      // body: TodoPage(todoList: _todoList,), // this is work well
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _openDlg,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.list), title: Text('Todo')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), title: Text('Other')),
        ],
        currentIndex: _activeIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: _onMenuTap,
      ),
    );
  }


  _onMenuTap(int index){
    setState(() {
      _activeIndex = index;
    });
  }

  _openDlg(){
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return SimpleDialog(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: FloatingActionButton(child: Text('submit'), onPressed: _addTodo,),
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }

  _addTodo(){
    print(_controller.text);
    setState(() {
      _todoList.add(_controller.text);
    });
  }
}

class TodoPage extends StatefulWidget{
  TodoPage({Key key, this.todoList}): super(key: key);
  List<String> todoList;
  _TodoPageState createState() => _TodoPageState();
}

class _TodoPageState extends State<TodoPage>{

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    print('build TodoPage');
    return Column(
      children: _buildTodoList(),
    );
  }

  List <Widget> _buildTodoList(){
    return widget.todoList.map((todo){
      return Text(todo, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),);
    }).toList();
  }
}


class OtherPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Center(child: Text('Other Page'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is logical.

You are reusing an existing instance of a `Widget`, and widgets are immutable.
As such, the framework notice that the instance of the widget did not change and doesn't call `build` to optimize performances.

Your problem being, you violated the rule of widgets being immutable, which makes this optimization break your app.

What you did:

```dart
class MyState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  SomeWidget myWidget = SomeWidget()..someProperty = "initial value";

  void onSomething() {
    setState(() {
      myWidget.someProperty = "new value";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return myWidget;
  }
}
```

What you should instead do:

```dart
class MyState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  SomeWidget myWidget = SomeWidget(someProperty: "initial value");

  void onSomething() {
    setState(() {
      myWidget = SomeWidget(someProperty: "new value");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return myWidget;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, just don't cache the widget instance at all.

Comment: `"return myWidget();"` does `SomeWidget` have `call()` method?

Comment: @pskink It was just a typo actually haha

Comment: it was my first thought too :-)

Comment: This works more reliably if you include a key in the widget constructor that is different after calling onSomething(). Which is easy to do with UniqueKey().

Comment: @jwehrle : UniqueKey worked great for my use case but just want to know is there any side effect of using that?

Comment: @MalavSoni quite possibly. UniqueKey ensures rebuild of widget every time parent rebuilds. So, for example, with a TextField even a change in focus will cause a rebuild. Which means always assigning a UniqueKey to a TextField (or something containing a TextField) can prevent user from actually opening Keyboard. One way to get around would be to make the key a member variable and only reassign to a new UniqueKey when you know that the widget should be rebuilt. (Hope that makes sense).